# How to properly expose spark in kubernetes outside the cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have Spark running in Kubernetes with 1 master and 3 workers. It's able to run a simple CalculatePi example if I run it within a container in the k8s cluster (so Spark is in a working state). I created a service exposing a `externalIPs` and was able to `telnet <ip address> 7077` successfully, but when running `spark-submit --master spark://<ip>:7077` with my `.jar` I get the error

```
ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend:70 - Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

Along with some others.

But if i `kubectl cp` it to one of the spark worker containers and run `spark-submit` within that container it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Edit: The Spark configuration is identical to the [official Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/spark), except I added an additional service to the `spark-master-deployment.yaml` file, which is identical to the existing ClusterIP service except with a `externalIPs` property to expose it outside the Kubernetes cluster:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ template "master-fullname" . }}-exposed
  labels:
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    component: "{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Values.Master.Component }}"
spec:
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.Master.ServicePort }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.Master.ContainerPort }}
  selector:
    component: "{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Values.Master.Component }}"
  externalIPs:
  - <the IP address of one of the Kubernetes nodes here>
```

Comment: What IP address are you using? ClusterIP? publicIP?

Comment: it's the IP address of a worker node of the k8s cluster, hosted on an EC2 instance in AWS. It's a private IP, but reachable if connected to a VPN. `telnet` resolves successfully to that IP outside the k8s cluster

Comment: Is it an IP address assigned to a physical interface? or a Kubernetes internal IP?

Comment: It is not a Kubernetes internal IP.

Comment: @Mike could you share the configuration for Deployment and Services in Kubernetes for your Spark installation?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev i just updated my question

Comment: telnet!? :\\\\\